# Logical operations in django filter

Tags: python, django, django-q

I need to get my queryset where:

```
(a="a" AND b=None) OR (a=None AND b="b")
```

I know about Q objects in django, but this syntax doesn't works:

```
cls.objects.filter(models.Q(a="a", b=None) | models.Q(a=None, b="b"))
```

I am absolutely sure my database contains expected objects. But all I get is the empty queryset.
I guess there is some problem with syntax here. But where?
[excepted rows picture. i need only first one and second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfItG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cls.objects.filter(models.Q(a="a", b='None') | models.Q(a='None' AND b="b"))
```

try this

Comment: `cls.objects.filter(models.Q(a="a", b__isnull=True) | models.Q(a__isnull=True, b="b")) `  
the similar result - empty queryset

Comment: can you tell me what do you have in a column in your database? and are you trying to find all with a and b strings in them??

Comment: i have two columns called `a` and `b`. and all i need to get - the objects with strings equals my request params. i mean if there is some row where `a == "a"` and where `b == None` in database - i need that row.  if `a == "aaaa"` i do not need it.

Comment: can you show the 2 rows which you are trying to get

Comment: [excepted rows](https://i.imgur.com/maQi0uU.png)  
link for copy: https://i.imgur.com/maQi0uU.png

Comment: Thank you, your answer was pushed me to the right way