# How to filter Django model data using the logged-in users with multiple objects

Tags: django, filter, model

I am new to Django and trying to figure out how to filter data using the logged-in users with multiple objects.

When the user logged in, the user should be able to see the book which was authored by him, and also he is co-authored some books.

```
Models.py

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    co_authors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='co_authored_by')
```

```
views.py

@login_required()
def booklist(request):
    book=Book.objects.filter(author =request.user, co_authors =request.user)
    context = {
        'book':book
    }
    return render(request, "contracts/booklist.html", context)
```

Tried using Q and or logic not able pass both filters to the template.

Comment: Please, see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186658/logical-operations-in-django-filter)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Q` for complex lookups, in this case you need and **OR** `(|)` operator

```py
from django.db.models import Q

...
book=Book.objects.filter(Q(author=request.user) | Q(co_authors=request.user))
...
```

You can take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: For example, if x is the logged-in user and X is the author of ABC book and Co-author of XYZ book with Y and Z as coauthor but template render the data only of ABC Book or XYZ book but not both the book. And if there are multiple xo-author it does not work shows duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {% if user.is_authenticated %} in the template as well.